# Routing catch go wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to write a C# ASP.NET app and I have a routing problem and I do not know how to move on:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultArticole",
    "{limba}/Art-{id}/{titluPagina}",
    new { controller = "Pagini", action = "Index", limba = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional, titluPagina = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultPagini",
    "{limba}/{paginaCurenta}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", limba = UrlParameter.Optional, paginaCurenta = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

All I want is that on uri like:

```
/Art-10/title
```

or

```
/en/Art-10/title
```

to be caught by `DefaultArticole`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to define two routes for your `Pagini` controller:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultArticole", "{limba}/Art-{id}/{titluPagina}",
    new { controller = "Pagini", action = "Index", limba = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional, titluPagina = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("DefaultArticoleDefaultLimba", "Art-{id}/{titluPagina}",
    new { controller = "Pagini", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, titluPagina = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then in your `PaginiController` you can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string limba, int id, string titluPagina)
{
    // Set the language to default, if none given (via /Art-10/title route)
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(limba)) limba = "en";
    // Your actual stuff here
    return View();
}
```